# How can I add an implied year to a string which does not specify the year?

Tags: mysql, perl, sed, awk

I have to download many text files from a website. Then I have to put it into a MySQL database, but the file has lines of the form:

```
02/04 15:00 Some strings

03/03 15:00 other strings

01/12/2010 12:00 other strings

03/04 15:00 more strings

...
```

When the year is not explicitly written, it means that it is the current year. So I need to parse the file line by line and convert every date of the form `dd/mm` to a date of the form `dd/mm/yyyy` (where yyyy is the current year of course) before I put it into database.
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the current time is Jan 1st 00:00 or near to that time? Should it assume the year that just finished or the year that just started?

Comment: doesn't matter. it's not crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk -v year=$(date +%Y) 'match($1, "^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$") {$1 = $1"/"year} 1'`

or

`awk -v year=$(date +%Y) 'split($1, a, "/") == 2  {$1 = $1"/"year} 1'`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $pattern = qr(^(\d\d/\d\d) );#month/day at start of line followed by space
my $year = localtime->year;

while (<DATA>){
    s/$pattern/$1\/$year /;
    print;
}
__DATA__
02/04 15:00 Some strings
03/03 15:00 other strings
01/12/2010 12:00 other strings
03/04 15:00 more strings
```

Comment: No need for all of those unused temp vars: my $year = (localtime)[5] + 1900;

Comment: You can simplify localtime handling with core [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Piece) module. Also in replacement you match general whitespace and replace with space.

Comment: I edited my answer to incorporate the above suggestions. Thanks @tadmc and @bvr. I didn't know about Time::Piece.

Answer (score 2):

A little golfy perl solution:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '$yy=localtime->year; s{^(\d{2}/\d{2})(\s)}{$1/$yy$2}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
year=`date +%Y`
sed "s|^\([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]\) |\1/$year |" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{y=strftime("%Y")}length($1)==5{$1=$1"/"y}1' file
02/04/2011 15:00 Some strings
03/03/2011 15:00 other strings
01/12/2010 12:00 other strings
03/04/2011 15:00 more strings

$ ruby -ane '$F[0].size==5 && $F[0]=$F[0]+"/"+Time.now.year.to_s;puts $F.join(" ")' file
```